# How do I change my user account domain in Team Foundation Server

Tags: tfs

We are migrating from one domain to another, and I'd like to be able to keep my same workspace, user settings, history, etc.

Is there any way to change just my domain or log in name within Team Foundation Server?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer, but I do know enough about TFS to be a little bit frightened about it.

If I understand you correctly, you want to change the domain that your users are authenticating as but you want to keep all the same user id's pointing to the same accounts in TFS?

TFS is highly integrated with Active Directory, and stores AD SID's around the place.  It also is pretty sensitive to changes in the AD configuration.

I seem to remember one customer that I know of who has done this before, but I cannot find details of it now.  I think that your best bet is to call Microsoft Product Support and raise a support incident about it as I have a vague memory that there was some special tool that had to be ran - but I could be mistaken.

Good luck,

Martin.

Answer (score 0):

I know your login name is done through your Domain Controller but I dont know how that will work with switching which domain your TFS is on. Are you trying to move which domain the TFS installation is on or which domain your PC is on?

Comment: The domain that TFS is on is not changing.  My PC's domain has changed, so I'll need TFS to reflect that as well.  I'd like to change my account in TFS from ABC\JDOE to XYX\JDOE.